# DOJO or ExtJS?

Tags: ajax

These are the Complete Demos for DOJO and ExtJS

DOJO
http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dijit/themes/themeTester.html

ExtJS
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/themes/index.html

Which one of them is better - Aesthetically pleasing and performant both ?
Also which of them would be a better Candidate for Webkit based Desktop/Mobile Application ?

Comment: I think both of them are mind-blowing :) I see extjs doesnt has a context-menu in its Tree widget , maybe it can be implemented easily

Comment: Very easily: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?2430-TreePanel-with-Context-Menu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aesthetics are subjective, and not quantifiable.  I personally prefer the look of ExtJS, but that’s me.  I'm sure others prefer the look of Dojo.

Dojo is free; ExtJS is commercial (unless it’s an in-house app).

ExtJS has a pretty awesome API, once you get used to how it thinks.  It’s very object oriented, and has a great plugin/extension eco system.

I can't comment on performance, never benchmarked them.

The requirement of which to use would come down to the project requirements.  Both can be themed, so default aesthetics may not be as important as the breadth of functionality they offer.  The ExtJS grids are exceptionally powerful, so if you're doing a lot of grid based data work that might be a plus in Ext's direction.

Compare their features, and align that to your needs.  If no clear winner presents its self, and money isn't a problem, just choose the one you feel most productive working with.